# ValidationMessageFor extension in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to create an extension method for `ValidationMessageFor` so that I can control the display of message better. I see some very old examples but they are quite old and not working in .NET Core.

I have the following extension method:

```
public static HtmlString ValidationMessageForCustom<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    return new HtmlString("test");
}
```

I'm using it like this:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageForCustom(model => model.Ext)
```

However when I compile I get this error:

> Error CS1061: 'IHtmlHelper<Shared_ViewModel>' does not contain a definition for 'MyValidationMessageFor' and no accessible extension method 'MyValidationMessageFor' accepting a first argument of type 'IHtmlHelper<Shared_ViewModel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: The error mentions `MyValidationMessageFor` but you extension method is named `ValidationMessageForCustom`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message has indicated  that you should pass `IHtmlHelper<T>`instead of
`HtmlHelper<TModel>`  into your extension method

```
public static HtmlString ValidationMessageForCustom<TModel, TProperty>(this IHtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
        {
            return new HtmlString("test");
        }
```

It works now:

[image]